# How can I relocate mutated columns next to the original colums?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, across, relocate

I have made a function which mutates across columns and creates new named columns from each of them. The new colums are put to the right side of the dataframe whereas I would like to have them adjacent to each of the original columns. I am looking for a solution that will generalise to any dataframe this function might be used on, writing a select statement to reorder the columns is not automatic enough for my use case.

```
test_data <- data.frame(data_col_1 = c(1,2,3),
                        data_col_2 = c(1,2,3),
                        data_col_3 = c(1,2,3),
                        another_column = c("a","b","c"))


perc_funct <- function(df, columns, numerator){
  
p_f <- function(x, numerator){
  
  (x/numerator)*100
}
    j <- df %>%
     mutate( across({{columns}}, 
                    .fns = list(perc = ~p_f(.x, numerator)),
                    .names = "{col}_{fn}"))# need to figure out a way to get the columns ordered 
return(j)
}

test_data %>% perc_funct(columns = starts_with("data"), numerator = 1)
```

The output currently puts all the new colums to the right.

"data_col_1"      "data_col_2"      "data_col_3"  "another_column"    "data_col_1_perc" "data_col_2_perc" "data_col_3_perc"

The output I want puts each new colums to the right of each old column.
"data_col_1"   "data_col_1_perc"   "data_col_2"  "data_col_2_perc"    "data_col_3"   "data_col_3_perc" "another_column"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I typically sort the columns with `select(sort(names(.)))` afterwards:

```r
library(dplyr)

test_data %>% 
  perc_funct(columns = starts_with("data"), numerator = 1) %>% 
  select(sort(names(.)))

#>   data_col_1 data_col_1_perc data_col_2 data_col_2_perc data_col_3
#> 1          1             100          1             100          1
#> 2          2             200          2             200          2
#> 3          3             300          3             300          3
#>   data_col_3_perc
#> 1             100
#> 2             200
#> 3             300
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

#### What if I have other columns I want to keep in the same spot?

It's just a matter of nesting my solution above together with other `select` statements or dplyr verbs. You might have to save the dataframe with the unsorted columns as a intermediate step.

###### Example 1

Here is an example with three other columns, where I want some to come first, some to come last, and others to come anywhere but stay together.

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- 
  test_data %>% 
  mutate(first_col = 1, other_columns = 100, last_col = 999) %>%
  perc_funct(columns = starts_with("data"), numerator = 1)

# Unsorted:
df %>% names()
#> [1] "data_col_1"      "data_col_2"      "data_col_3"      "first_col"      
#> [5] "other_columns"   "last_col"        "data_col_1_perc" "data_col_2_perc"
#> [9] "data_col_3_perc"

# Sorted:
df %>% 
  select(
    first_col,
    df %>% select(starts_with("data")) %>% names() %>% sort(), 
    everything(),
    last_col
  ) 
#>   first_col data_col_1 data_col_1_perc data_col_2 data_col_2_perc data_col_3
#> 1         1          1             100          1             100          1
#> 2         1          2             200          2             200          2
#> 3         1          3             300          3             300          3
#>   data_col_3_perc other_columns last_col
#> 1             100           100      999
#> 2             200           100      999
#> 3             300           100      999
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

###### Example 2

There's also an alternative using `col_bind()`:

If you just want your new columns last, but sorted together with the columns they were created from, you can also do something like:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  select(
    -starts_with("data")
  ) %>% bind_cols(
    df %>% 
      select(
        df %>% select(starts_with("data")) %>% names() %>% sort()
      )
  )
#>   first_col other_columns last_col data_col_1 data_col_1_perc data_col_2
#> 1         1           100      999          1             100          1
#> 2         1           100      999          2             200          2
#> 3         1           100      999          3             300          3
#>   data_col_2_perc data_col_3 data_col_3_perc
#> 1             100          1             100
#> 2             200          2             200
#> 3             300          3             300
```

Comment: Thanks. That works on my test_data (I should have made trickier test data), but if I had aditional columns that were not part of the tidyselect statement they would also get sorted and I would want to avoid reordering any existing columns in the dataframe.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, and  was wondering whether to include this in the answer from the beginning. I have updated my answer now.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to move columns using dplyr (since version 1.0.0) is to use `relocate()`.  `relocate()` supports tidyselect semantics but importantly acts only on the selected column(s) leaving all other columns in place.  In your case, you can `grep()` and `sort()` on the columns beginning with `data`.

```
test_data <- data.frame(column_1 = 1:3,
                        data_col_1 = c(1,2,3),
                        data_col_2 = c(1,2,3),
                        data_col_3 = c(1,2,3),
                        another_column = c("a","b","c"))


test_data %>%
  perc_funct(columns = starts_with("data"), numerator = 1) %>%
  relocate(sort(grep("^data", names(.), value = TRUE)), .before = data_col_1)

  column_1 data_col_1 data_col_1_perc data_col_2 data_col_2_perc data_col_3 data_col_3_perc another_column
1        1          1             100          1             100          1             100              a
2        2          2             200          2             200          2             200              b
3        3          3             300          3             300          3             300              c
```

The `.before` (or `.after`) argument specifies where to relocate the columns, in this case you can place them before `data_col_1`.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be to use `contains()` and the column order from the orginal dataframe

```
test_data <- data.frame(column_1 = 1:3,
                        data_col_1 = c(1,2,3),
                        data_col_2 = c(1,2,3),
                        data_col_3 = c(1,2,3),
                        another_column = c("a","b","c"))


test_data %>% perc_funct(columns = starts_with("data"), numerator = 1) %>% 
  select(contains(test_data %>% colnames()))
```